# Implementing rating in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, numbers, rating

I am trying to do rating implementation in angular js. I have a star and on click of the star , I am supposed to display numbers (1, 2 , 3) inside a rounded horizontal bar. Now say if i click 2 from this bar, number 2 should be returned back by hiding the horizontal bar. Please help me in doing this. I have tried displaying the star as below. But unsure how to implement the numbers inside the bar onclick of this star.
I am able to find queries related to star rating, but nothing about this particular scenario.

The below code displays the star icon. All I need to do is associate a horizontal bar with numbers on click of this star icon. It would be great if could provide me with some guidelines on how to do this

```
<div style="float:left;clear:both;padding-top:2px">
    <b style="font-weight:400">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-star-outline tabfont" style="font-size:25px;color:#443D6F"></i>
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
    </b>
</div>
```

Adding the controller code:

```
.controller('QuestionaireCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.heading = "Questionaire";
  // $scope.rating = true;
  // $scope.responses = {    
  //   "q1":"",
  //   "rating":0
  // };
  $scope.ratingData = {
   "CISCO":{
      "headcount":"30",
      "questions":{
         "Contractual/Commercial Aspects":[
            {
               "question":"SLA/SLO is reported on time, everytime?",
               "rating":"1"
            },
            {
               "question":"Test outcomes are aligned with Contractual commitments?",
               "rating":"2"
            },
            {
               "question":"Test scope is clear and baselined?",
               "rating":"2"
            },
            {
               "question":"Contractual Dependencies with respect to  resource, infrastructure, Schedule and costs are defined and managed?",
               "rating":"3"
            },
            {
               "question":"Contractual commitments and base solution are understood by the Delivery team?",
               "rating":"2"
            },
            {
               "question":"Productivity commitments are delivered to the client?",
               "rating":"2"
            },
            {
               "question":"Profitability and revenue improvement opportunities are continuously identified?",
               "rating":"2"
            }
         ],
```

Comment: Did you try to write any javascript?

Comment: yes, I have the controller code written , which has information on the rating chosen.

Comment: share the controller as well

Comment: Added the controller code as well

Comment: May be a div with numbers inside it , to be displayed on click of the star

Comment: can you please post your code in plunkr will be easy to resolve the issue for all

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jy9pp76d/

Comment: please check the above URL. Though I am not able to post the complete code, I have posted a part of it.

Comment: Try using angular bootstrap it has directive for this